# C++ Convert String with commas separated values to vector<int>

Tags: c++, string, optimization, vector, transform

I think the title it's pretty explanatory, anyways, here's what I'm trying to do:
given an input of a string of integers between 0 and 9, every number separated with a comma, convert it into a std::vector. I already know the lenght of the string so the vector is already resized properly

I know it has been answered before, ([How can I read and parse CSV files in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120140/how-can-i-read-and-parse-csv-files-in-c)) but I'm looking for a solution without external libraries (it's for an assignement).

1) this version works but I think it's very rudimental and I'm trying to improve it

```
string line;
vector<int> numers;
int i=0;
...
for (string::iterator it=line.begin(); it<line.end(); it=it+2){ //I need to skip commas
    numbers[i]=*it-48;
```

2) this is what I think would perform better, but can't get it  to work!

```
line.erase(std::remove(line.begin(), line.end(), ','), line.end());
transform(line.begin(),line.end(),numbers.begin(),[](const string &str){return stoi(str);});
```

this solution doesn't compile

Any better idea?

Comment: What does "can't get it to work" supposed to mean? Does it fail compile, or to you get a runtime error?

Comment: @StoryTeller i get a compiler error about *__result=__unary_op(*__first)

Comment: `std::string::begin()` returns an iterator that iterates over every character of the string. You need to split at the commas.

Comment: @SimonKraemer i tried with 
    'line.erase(std::remove(line.begin(), line.end(), ','), line.end());'  
but stil get the same compiler error